# APEX 3.2: How to change the color of the DELETE_CONFIRM_MSG Popup?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working on an apex application 3.2 and i want to change the text color of the delete confirm popup when the user click on the delete button. I tried to put the following code in the  DELETE_CONFIRM_MSG shortcut but it doesnt match:

```
<p><span style="color:red">Would you like to perform this delete action?</span</p>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The confirm dialog is an alert that is thrown by javascript and interpreted by your browser. There is no way to apply css to that. If you ensist, you should create your own message box, I'd suggest jQueryUI dialog for that. Also it would require to rewrite the normal function that is triggered when you do a delete: "apex.confirm(htmldb_delete_message,'MULTI_ROW_DELETE');".

Here the 'MULTI_ROW_DELETE' is your page submit condition, the rest is the javascipt that throws the alert, so you need to make something like myFunction(message, submit){...}
and fill the dots with a call to a dialog box :)